# Force trailing slash except in a specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am forcing trailing slashes on my website but it's caused an issue with our Wiki, as it treats them as a blank page.

Want I want to do is force trailing slash except if in /wiki/. How would I do this?

Here is my current rule for it:

```
  # force trailing slash
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `RewriteCond` (*condition*) directive to create an exception for any URL that starts `/wiki/`.

For example:

```
# force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wiki/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

The `!` prefix on the regex `^/wiki/` negates the expression, so it is successful when it does *not* match.

You will need to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!